# Как правильно распараллелить поразрядную сортировку?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, mpi

мне нужно организовать параллельную сортировку с применением технологи MPI. С последовательным алгоритмом я разобрался.

Помогите разобраться с тем, какой конкретно участок кода можно распараллелить в моём алгоритме. У меня появились трудности в понимании, поскольку каждый промежуточный результат сортировки нужен для корректной сортировки последующего разряда (т.е. отсортировали по единицам - затем по десяткам и т.д.). А если разделить массив на потоки (например, на 6 частей) - будет выполнена только локальная сортировка.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void fillArray(int* arr, int size) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
}

void swap(int* first, int* second) 
{
    int temp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
}

void shuffleArray(int* arr, int size) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[rand() % (size - 1)]);
    }
}

void printArrayToFile(int* arr, int size, ofstream &file) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        file << arr[i] << " ";
        if (!((i + 1) % 15))
            file << endl;
    }
    file << endl << endl;
}

bool isSeq(int* arr, int size) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] + 1 != arr[i + 1])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void copyArr(int* target, int* src, int size) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        target[i] = src[i];
    }
}

int* getRankGroup(int* arr, int size, int rank, int digit) 
{
    // 1234 rank - 3
    int* group, groupSize = 0, targetDigit;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        targetDigit = arr[i];
        int j = rank;
        while (j > 1)
        {
            targetDigit /= 10;
            j--;
        }
        if ((targetDigit % 10) == digit)
            groupSize++;
    }
    group = new int[groupSize + 1];
    group[0] = groupSize;
    for (int i = 0, k = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        targetDigit = arr[i];
        int j = rank;
        while (j > 1)
        {
            targetDigit /= 10;
            j--;
        }
        if ((targetDigit % 10) == digit) 
        {
            group[k] = arr[i];
            k++;
        }   
    }
    return group;
}

int getMaxArrRank(int* arr, int size) 
{
    int rank = 0, max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
    }
    while (max) 
    {
        rank++;
        max /= 10;
    }
    return rank;
}

int* radixSort(int* arr, int size)
{
    int* result = new int[size];
    int* temp = new int[size];
    int* group, rank = getMaxArrRank(arr, size);
    copyArr(temp, arr, size);
    for (int i = 1; i <= rank; i++) 
    {
        int resultI = 0;
        for (int j = 9; j > -1; j--)
        {
            group = getRankGroup(temp, size, i, j);
            for (int k = 1; k <= group[0]; k++, resultI++)
            {
                result[resultI] = group[k];
            }
            delete[] group;
        }
        copyArr(temp, result, size);
    }
    delete[] temp;
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int size, threadId, numOfThreads;
    int* arr, * resL, * resP;
    ofstream shuffled, sortedL, sortedP;
    if (argc > 1) 
    {
        size = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Size isn't specified. Default size = 100" << endl;
        size = 100;
    }
    arr = new int[size];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numOfThreads);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &threadId);
    if (threadId == 0) 
    {
        
        shuffled.open("shuffled.txt"); sortedL.open("sortedL.txt"); sortedP.open("sortedP.txt");
        fillArray(arr, size);
        shuffleArray(arr, size);
        printArrayToFile(arr, size, shuffled);
        resL = radixSort(arr, size);
        printArrayToFile(resL, size, sortedL);
    }

    MPI_Bcast(arr, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    ///

    MPI_Reduce(NULL, resP, size, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (threadId == 0)
    {
        shuffled.close(); sortedL.close(); sortedP.close();
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Разобрался в технологии MPI и пришёл к выводу о том, что 1 поток должен собирать данные с других потоков, которые будут сортировать массивы по отдельным символам.

Однако, осталась ошибка в коде, которую я не смог найти. Долго пытался разобраться, почему моя программа сортирует массив только до 5 разряда (на 6-ом один поток почему то не возвращает массив из функции getRankGroup), но так и не нашёл причину. В чём может быть причина?

```
void radixSortMPI(int* arr, int size, int* resultArr, int threadId, int numOfThreads)
{
    int* temp = new int[size];
    int* group;
    if (threadId == 0)
        copyArr(temp, arr, size);
    for (int rank = 1; rank <= getMaxArrRank(arr, size); rank++)
    {
        MPI_Bcast(temp, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        int resultI = 0;
        // Get data
        if (threadId == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 9; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                int* recvBuf = new int[size];
                MPI_Recv(recvBuf, size, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, j,
                    MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                for (int k = 1; k <= recvBuf[0]; k++, resultI++)
                {
                    resultArr[resultI] = recvBuf[k];
                }
                delete[] recvBuf;
            }
            copyArr(temp, resultArr, size);
        }
        // Evaluations
        else 
        {
            int step = ceil(10. / (numOfThreads - 1));
            int digit = (threadId - 1) * step;
            for (int j = digit; (j < (digit + step)) && (j < 10); j++) 
            {
                group = getRankGroup(temp, size, rank, j);
                MPI_Send(group, group[0] + 1, MPI_INT, 0, j, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                delete[] group;
            }
        }
    }
    delete[] temp;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: По единицам сортируйте в одном потоке. После сортировки по единицам исходный массив будет состоять из десяти групп, которые друг относительно друга расположены в правильном порядке, но внутри групп элементы могут быть не упорядочены. Следовательно группы можно сортировать независимо друг от друга в десять потоков. После сортировки по десяткам массив будет состоять из ста групп, которые можно сортировать независимо... и т.д. P.S. Ваш код не изучал, поэтому какой конкретно участок кода нужно параллелить не подскажу.